# dynamic textbox watermarker remove message on key press

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery

i have a text-box in my tree that is generated run-time for giving the user to enter the node  in the textbox i have given a water-marker message to enter something on the click function of textbox i have  cleared the textbox but on the key press event also i want the text to be cleared but not able to do it i have pasted my code

```
function CreateTextBoxNode(SpnPrntId) {
var elem = document.createElement("input");
elem.type = "text";
elem.id = "txtParent";
elem.value = "Enter node name";
$(elem).css("color", "DarkGray");
elem.setAttribute('onblur', 'SetSpanValueForParent("' + SpnPrntId + '")');
$(elem).keypress(function(e) {
    SetEnterValue(SpnPrntId, e);
});
$(elem).click(function() {
    textClick();
});
$(elem).focus(function() {
    textClick();
});
return elem;
```

}

```
function SetEnterValue(prntID, e) {
var key = checkBrowser(e);
if (key == 13) {
    SetSpanValueForParent(prntID);
}
```

}

function textClick() {
    $("#txtParent").val('');
}

On key press when enter is pressed i have to append the value into some span i also tried its focus function so when the first time the textbox come with focused set it removes the message.

Comment: could you clarify what your question is?

Comment: though i got one work around for time being i was looking for some thing better here is what i have done function SetEnterValue(prntID, e) {
    var key = checkBrowser(e);
    if (key == 13) {
        SetSpanValueForParent(prntID);
    }
    else {
        if ($("#txtParent").val() == "Enter node name") {
            $("#txtParent").val('');
        }
    }
} it has solved the issue for time being but i was not into string comparison as it is risky to do this stuff

Comment: @rock i wanted to clear the water marker message on key press

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it would be a lot easier for you to use a [placeholder](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder) which will work in many modern browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Etc), and then maybe a [jquery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/input-placeholder) to make it work with the incompatible browsers.

Here's another really simple version
https://github.com/brandonweiss/jquery-placeholder

I've used this approach in my web apps and it works great. The best part is the reusability of it.  Every time you need a watermark, you simply add the placeholder tag to your input and you're done.

```
<input placeholder="Enter a valid email address" name="email" id="email" />
```

Comment: You have suggested the placeholder i am working MVC so No gain here with server controls

Comment: this is not a server control. It's a new "standard" in HTML5. The jquery pluggin adds placeholder support to NON html5 browsers. This has nothing to do with server side at all. I to use MVC

Comment: please have a look at the links I posted (3 of them)